# How to fix "WARNING:tensorflow:@custom_gradient grad_fn has 'variables' in signature, but no ResourceVariables were used on the forward pass"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow-probability

I have been getting this warning when using `model.fit()` or even `model.summary()`. Using (on Windows 10):

- Tensorflow 2.6.2
- Tensorflow Probability 0.14
- Keras 2.6

Also tested on Google Colab with `tf==2.8, tfp==0.16, keras==2.8`, without any change.

Tried to downgrade Tensorflow and TF-probability as suggusted [here (for a different implementation)](https://github.com/theislab/scCODA/issues/40) but did not work. My model is this, however I've had the same issue with different hidden layers and also when used a functional API:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(keras.Input(shape=(dataset.shape[1],1)))
model.add(tfkl.Conv1D(128, kernel_size = dataset.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(tfkl.Conv1D(16, kernel_size = 1, activation='softplus'))
model.add( tfkl.Flatten())
model.add(tfkl.Dense(16, activation='softplus'))
model.add(tfkl.Dense(1, use_bias = 1))
model.add(tfpl.DistributionLambda(
    lambda t: tfd.Chi2(df= abs(t[..., :1])
                        )))
```

Note that I'm not having the same issue when using `tfd.Normal` (only `tfd.Chi2` and `tfd.Gamma` don't work). Anyone faced the same issue?